# Can I tell whether the user unlocked the iPhone with TouchID or passcode when acting on a notification?

Tags: ios, touch-id

I would like to make an app which will require TouchID identification (not passcode). I would like them to "swipe right" on a notification and unlock with TouchID. If they unlock with passcode, I want the app to know. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no indication as to whether the device was unlocked by a passcode or a TouchID, and if you think it through there would be little benefit in diferentiating between the two.

If you know the passcode you can modify TouchID enrolments, therefore TouchID isn't inherently more secure in terms of an unlock event.  There may be some benefits in terms of preventing people from 'shoulder surfing' a passcode and it is certainly more convenient.